# Weird "T" character to right of UITableView when using sectionNameKeyPath

Tags: ios, uitableview

Anyone seen this before? Notice in the image below the small capital "T" character in the middle right side on my dynamic table view.

This only happens if I set a sectionNameKeyPath in my initWithFetchRequest:request. If I set sectionNameKeyPath to nil, this goes away (as do my section headers)

[image]

Comment: Post the image elsewhere and put a link to it - or delete this question. It's silly to ask a question about something we can't see.

Comment: And even as it is, you _could_ have shown some code...

Comment: Yah good point... here is a link  http://postimg.org/image/4jaovmzrt/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That "T" is the table's index. If you don't want it, don't have an index.

There is only one letter in the index because there is only one section and its name begins with "T" (for "Thursday").

Comment: thanks.  haha.  i should have realized that.  All i had to do to fix this was remove the implementations of sectionForSectionIndexTitle and sectionIndexTitlesForTableView.